# Maven: non-parseable POM when using jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

Hi I'm new to jenkins & nexus so, I'm trying to push the jar file to nexus. but when I building the job I'm getting the error like this:

The project  (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\job5\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\job5\pom.xml: Duplicated tag: 'repository' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n\t... @47:14)  @ line 47, column 14 -> [Help 2]

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.scmgalaxy.mavensample</groupId>
  <artifactId>yoodle</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <name>my-maven</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>sample_nexus</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/sample_nexus/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
    <id>maven-releases</id>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>maven-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
  </snapshotRepository>

</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Read the error message please `Duplicated tag: 'repository' ` also the line number is given...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POM file is not a valid XML file. The error message hints on a duplicate `repository` tag.

The `<distributionManagement>` section specifies where your Maven artifacts should be uploaded. You can have only one `repository` section in here. Otherwise, it's not clear to which repository the generated artifacts should be uploaded.

Try to remove one of the `repository` sections from the POM and re-run the Maven build.